# LTE Standard. Where to begin?

Tags: lte

I've started working as a wireless engineer fresh from college. I wanted to learn LTE standard and I don't know where to begin. I was wondering if you could guide me through this process. I found some sources online, but I don't want to jump into it.
Do I need to remember all the details? What parts of the standards do I need to learn/memorize?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: This can be daunting, can you clarify what your technical interests might be (we're signal processing here but LTE also involves networking, digital hardware design, analog hardware design, software, RF, microwaves, propagation, antennas, ...)? Do you have current or upcoming work opportunities that involve LTE or are you preparing yourself for such possible opportunities?

Comment: If your background in DSP is weak, I have a course coming up starting next week that covers all the requisite background leading to future study of the PHY layer in LTE; it does not get into "OFDM" but provides detailed digital filter design and the FFT applicable to wireless implementations: https://ieeeboston.org/event/digital-signal-processing-webinar/?instance_id=3435

Comment: Buy the book [LTE – The UMTS Long Term Evolution: From Theory to Practice](https://www.amazon.fr/LTE-UMTS-Evolution-Theory-Practice/dp/0470660252) and read what interests you. For some details https://www.sharetechnote.com/ is a good ressource.

Comment: I agree with Dan and Alex... having said that, another book I like is "Fundamentals of LTE" by Ghosh.